# KeyError: 'BANDS' and NameError: 'bands'

Tags: python, remote-sensing, anaconda, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to follow this tutorial: [land cover fastai](https://github.com/sentinel-hub/eo-learn/blob/master/examples/land-cover-fastai/deep_lulc_walkthrough.ipynb)
And while executing the workflow, I got this error:

```
eopatch 0 has been processed!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-2f6c45c1fa5e> in <module>()
     13     print("eopatch {} has been processed!".format(idx))
     14     # png_gen('eopatch_{}'.format(idx))
---> 15     png_gen(op.join(path_out_sampled, 'eopatch_{}'.format(idx)), inference=False)
     16     print("Saving RGB, LULC and Inds PNG to eopatch_{} for the coming ML pipeline".format(idx))
     17     # del 'eopatch_{}'.format(idx)

<ipython-input-18-419252da44d2> in png_gen(patch, inference)
     43         if not op.isdir(inds_path):
     44             makedirs(inds_path)
---> 45         for i in range(len(bands)):
     46             # Switch R, G, B band index from bands
     47             rgb = color_scale(bands[i][..., [2, 1, 0]]).astype("uint8")

NameError: name 'bands' is not defined
```

This is the code where the error occurs:

```
def color_scale(arr):
    """correct the RGB bands to be a composed bands of value between 0 255 for visualization purpose

    Args:
        arr: RGB bands in numpy array 
    Return:
        str_arr: numpy array that values range from 0 to 255 for visualization
    """
    str_arr = (arr + 1) * 127.5
    return str_arr

def png_gen(patch, inference=False):
    """Save RGB, spectral info and labeled images for the coming deep learning

    Args:
        patch: Saved eopatches for deep learning LULC training and prediction 
    Return:
        None: images in the PNG.
    """

    patch_data = EOPatch.load(patch)
    patch_dir, patch_id = patch.split("/")
    if inference == True:
        inds_path = "inds_inference"

        if not op.isdir(inds_path):
            makedirs(inds_path)
        for i in range(len(bands)):
            #get NDVI, NDWI and NDBI from the bands
            inds = color_scale(bands[i][..., [-3, -2, -1]]).astype("uint8")
            Image.fromarray(inds).save(op.join(inds_path, patch+'_'+str(i)+'.png'))

    else:
        lulc = patch_data.mask_timeless['LULC']
        lulc_path = "lulc_all"
        rgb_path = "rgb_all"
        inds_path = "inds_all"
        if not op.isdir(lulc_path):
            makedirs(lulc_path)
        if not op.isdir(rgb_path):
            makedirs(rgb_path)
        if not op.isdir(inds_path):
            makedirs(inds_path)
        for i in range(len(bands)):
            # Switch R, G, B band index from bands
            rgb = color_scale(bands[i][..., [2, 1, 0]]).astype("uint8")
            inds = color_scale(bands[i][..., [-3, -2, -1]]).astype("uint8")
            Image.fromarray(rgb).save(op.join(rgb_path, "{}_{}.png".format(patch_id, str(i))))
            Image.fromarray(inds).save(op.join(inds_path, "{}_{}.png".format(patch_id, str(i))))
            Image.fromarray(lulc).save(op.join(lulc_path, "{}_{}.png".format(patch_id, str(i))))
```

And this is the execution code:

```
pbar = tqdm(total=len(patchIDs))
for idx in range(len(patchIDs)):
    # define additional parameters of the workflow
    extra_param = {
        load: {'eopatch_folder': f'eopatch_{idx}'},
        spatial_sampling: {'seed': 42},
        save: {'eopatch_folder': f'eopatch_{idx}'}
    }

    workflow.execute(extra_param)
    print("eopatch {} has been processed!".format(idx))
    # png_gen('eopatch_{}'.format(idx))
    png_gen(op.join(path_out_sampled, 'eopatch_{}'.format(idx)), inference=False)
    print("Saving RGB, LULC and Inds PNG to eopatch_{} for the coming ML pipeline".format(idx))
    # del 'eopatch_{}'.format(idx)
    #shutil.rmtree(op.join(path_out_sampled, 'eopatch_{}'.format(idx)), ignore_errors=True)
    #print("eopatch_{} deleted!".format(idx))
    pbar.update(1)
```

patches are basically numpy arrays as explained in this documentation [EOPatch](https://eo-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/core/CoreOverview.html). And this is an example of the content of a patch I downloaded :

```
EOPatch(
  data: {
    BANDS: numpy.ndarray(shape=(55, 168, 167, 6), dtype=float32)
    CLP: numpy.ndarray(shape=(55, 168, 167, 1), dtype=float32)
    NDVI: numpy.ndarray(shape=(55, 168, 167, 1), dtype=float32)
    NDWI: numpy.ndarray(shape=(55, 168, 167, 1), dtype=float32)
    NORM: numpy.ndarray(shape=(55, 168, 167, 1), dtype=float32)
  }
  mask: {
    CLM: numpy.ndarray(shape=(55, 168, 167, 1), dtype=bool)
    IS_DATA: numpy.ndarray(shape=(55, 168, 167, 1), dtype=bool)
    IS_VALID: numpy.ndarray(shape=(55, 168, 167, 1), dtype=bool)
  }
  scalar: {}
  label: {}
  vector: {}
  data_timeless: {}
  mask_timeless: {
    LULC: numpy.ndarray(shape=(168, 167, 1), dtype=uint8)
    VALID_COUNT: numpy.ndarray(shape=(168, 167, 1), dtype=int64)
  }
  scalar_timeless: {}
  label_timeless: {}
  vector_timeless: {}
  meta_info: {
    maxcc: 0.8
    service_type: 'wcs'
    size_x: '10m'
    size_y: '10m'
    time_difference: datetime.timedelta(-1, 86399)
    time_interval: ['2017-01-01', '2017-12-31']
  }
  bbox: BBox(((500077.09501641133, 5100450.60685301), (501746.98615037295, 5102133.148677379)), crs=CRS('32633'))
  timestamp: [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 10, 4, 7), ..., datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 24, 9, 56, 27)], length=55
)
```

And this is how I can access bands for example: `BANDS=patch.data['BANDS']` or `BANDS=patch[FeatureType.DATA]['BANDS']` I tried both but I still got the same error.

PS: the original code does not contain `*others` or `BANDS=patch.data['BANDS']` (

This where the downloaded data are stored:

```
path_out_sampled = './eopatches_sampled_Slovenia/'
if not op.isdir(path_out_sampled):
    makedirs(path_out_sampled)
save = SaveToDisk(path_out_sampled, overwrite_permission=OverwritePermission.OVERWRITE_PATCH)
```

Comment: `png_gen` has this code in a couple of places, `for i in range(len(bands)):` but `bands` is not defined anywhere...

Comment: @user2856  I tried to add this ```bands=patch.data['BANDS'] ```  in   ```png_gen ``` but the error changes to ```keyError: 'BANDS' ``` originally it was ```NameError``` Where the error occurs for the second ```for i in range(len(bands))```  and only eopatch_0 gets processed before the error is raised.

Comment: Suggest you report the issue to the tutorial developers